# Python: Find a point on a uneven plane where the distance from an object is exactly a given value!

Tags: python

I like to identify a point (Global Vector) on a plane where the air-line distance to an object is f.e. exactly 1.5 bu. The point should be exactly on a line between the object and a target object.

To demonstrate the problem i have attached a picture. The left Empty should be the origin Object and the right one the target Object. As i said the image is only for demonstration purposes. The problem should be solved only in python and the locations of both Empties are Vector-Variables and not existing Objects.

[image: demonstration]

UPDATE:
I found an answer by myself

```
def pos_target():
    start = bpy.data.objects["Empty"].matrix_world.translation.copy()
    actualpos = start.copy()
    end = bpy.data.objects["Empty2"].matrix_world.translation.copy()
    vec = end - start 
    distance = 0.0
    max_distance = 1.5
    target = bpy.data.objects['Plane']
    while distance < max_distance:
        actualpos = actualpos + (1/10 * vec)
        raystart = actualpos.copy()
        rayend = raystart.copy()
        raystart[2]= 10.0
        rayend[2] = -10.0
        location = target.ray_cast(start=raystart,end=rayend)[0]
        distance = (actualpos - start).length
    bpy.data.objects["point"].location = location
```

It's not the exact point i was looking for but for my problem it's good enough. 
But is there a better Answer, maybe without a while-loop?

Comment: take a look at the [Mathutils classes](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils#module-mathutils) especially [Vector](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils#mathutils.Vector) has useful methods. Try write some code we can help if you really get stuck - and [obj.ray_cast](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=ray_cast#bpy.types.Object.ray_cast)

Comment: No. I have a given distance. You could imaginate the distance as radius of an circle around Empty A. I'm searching the coordinate of the intersection of the fictive circle and the the plane.

Comment: Okay, i made it not totaly clear. The intersection has to be between empty 1 and empty 2. The red line in my picture shows all possible points and i'm searching the point that has an 1.5bu air-line distance from empty A.

Comment: I found a solution. Maybe there's a better one?